# Google fonts not working in my specific system

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I am learning Web Development and used google fonts in my application. Everything worked fine for sometime and the google fonts stopped rendering at my application. I tried different browsers but it was all the same. Tried all the available solutions on the net and no fruitful result. All these while, I was thinking that the problem is in my code but when I opened google fonts website, none of the fonts loaded there too. [Here is the reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzdjP.png) . Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: Might be server was down. I just crosschecked and i was able to see the fonts. Check and or try in incognito mode.

Comment: can you post your font link tag and css declaration for this font? let me have a look.

Comment: I replaced google fonts with adobe fonts for now, but I wanna use google fonts as it is more standard.